# Need a DetachedCriteria query using AND and OR operators

Tags: java

This is my sql Query

```
SELECT * FROM userDb.payment_request pr, userDb.payment_request_log pl 
where pr.payment_request_id = pl.payment_request_id 
and  (pr.name like '%xyz%' or pl.status like '%sucx%');
```

I need to write this query in DetachedCriteria using hiberante.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @MounicaP please don't use comments for long pieces of code. Instead [edit] your question and put it there.